# How do I install Psychonauts from the recently released Humble Bundle V?

Tags: games

I have looked everywhere for "How to" but I can't find anything. I have Ubuntu 12.04.

How do I install Psychonauts from the recently released Humble indie Bundle V?

Comment: cd into the unzipped folder and then type `ls` in the terminal and post the output

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you install via the software center.

1. Go to the unique url you got for your bundle (something like https://www.humblebundle.com/downloads?key=notarealkey)

2 Click on the orange button right above the direct downloads.

3 Then you need to log in with your Ubuntu single sign on.

Choosing Psychonauts from the list that appears will open the SoftwareCenter where you just follow the procedure for buying the game (you won't actually be charged since youre purchase is already activated).

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the Psychonauts zip file. Go into the "psychonauts-linux-installer" folder and run "psychonaut-installer".

Comment: There is no zip folder nor `psychonauts-linux-installer` directory. Just `psychonauts-linux-05062013-bin` (no extension) and inside that: _data, guis, meta,_ and _scripts_.